# Sequences and series proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let {$a_{n}$} and {$b_{n}$} be sequences such that
>
> 1. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ converges;
> 2. there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for $n \ge N$ (in other words, {$b_{n}$} is the sequence with finitely many terms changed)
>
> Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n}$ converges.

My attempt- Since $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for $n \ge N$. I can assume some part of {$b_{n}$} for $n \ge N$ converges by limit comparison test. I'm not sure how to evaluate the other terms in {$b_{n}$}.

Comment: since only a finite number of terms is different form $a_n$ both sequences only differ by a finite amount

Comment: The series for $b_n$ is just the series $a_n$ with a different start. That's my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Set $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and $T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n b_k$ to be the partial sums. Then for $n > N$ you have

$$ T_n = \sum_{k=1}^N b_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^n b_k = \sum_{k=1}^N b_k + \sum_{k=N+1}^n a_k = \sum_{k=1}^N b_k + \sum_{k=1}^n a_k - \sum_{k=1}^N a_k = S_n + \sum_{k=1}^N (b_k - a_k). $$

Then let $n \to \infty$.

Comment: So $S_{n}$  and  $\sum_{k=1}^N a_{k}$ converge. I'm not sure what happens with  $\sum_{k=1}^N b_{k}$

Comment: @user1023: Note that we take $n \to \infty$ but leave $N$ fixed! That is, for the purpose of discussing the limits of $S_n,T_n$ when $n \to \infty$, we could have written the expression above as $T_n = S_n + C$. The term $C = \sum_{k=1}^N (b_k - a_k)$ doesn't change when we change $n$ and so is treated as a constant when we take the limit.

Comment: Thank you - I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

1. $a_n \not = b_n$ for $n< N_0$ i.e;

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b_n = \sum_{j=1}^{N_0-1} b_n + \sum_{j=N_0}^{\infty} a_n$$